# Sort function that returns the same sorting

Tags: javascript

In the framework I'm using, I have to pass in a sort function for my array.  The problem is that I don't want the sort to change. Is there a sort function that would return the exact same order?

Example:

```
var myObj= {
  myArray:['value2','value49','value16'],
  sort: function(a,b){}
}
myObj.myArray.sort(myObj.sort);
```

This is simplified but the sort function is required and will be executed on my array and I have no control over that. What would make it return the array in the exact same order?

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: A **sort** function, or a **compare** function? (One is the easiest function in the world, the second doesn't exist)

Comment: Can you share some code? And the exact definition of the expected sort- (or compare-) function

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
function () {return 0}
```

Just return 0 to leave the order unchanged for any pair of array elements. So, return it for all of them. The [MDN docs for .sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) describe the method's behavior upon returning 0:

> If compareFunction(a, b) returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with
>   respect to each other

Comment: That quote doesn't end there "... but sorted with respect to all different elements. Note: the ECMAscript standard does not guarantee this behaviour, and thus not all browsers (e.g. Mozilla versions dating back to at least 2003) respect this."